# jwt token missing scope with adal azure delegating

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Using adal-angular 1.0.17 and a single-tenant app registration (note: calling this **app 1**) in Azure that should delegate user rights to *another Azure app* (note: calling this **app 2**) but the jwt token is issued with any scope resulting in:

```
AADSTS50105: The signed in user ---- is not assigned to a role for the application '<another Azure app>'
```

The Azure Api permission on **app 1** have a permission == "user_impersonation" against **app 2** which should allow access to **app 2** on behalf of the signed-in user by **app 1**.  Looking at the scopes defined by **app 2** in the portal the *user_impersonation* scope is defined consenting Admins and users (enabled).

Tried using the extraQueryParameter setting in the adal configuration:

```
 {
    ....
    extraQueryParameter: 'scope=user_impersonation'
 }
```

But the user still is deemed unassigned.  Other users that have explicitly been assigned to both **app 1** and **app 2** successfully proceed through the authorization.

Looking for tips or any better way to debug.

Comment: **user_impersonation** is the display name.  Even tried setting scope to the application id uri + "/user_impersonation" but same negative result.  The scope parameter is present in the url.

Comment: Under **Enterprise applications** if the *User assignment required?* flag is toggled from Yes to No then (without extra query parameters) delegating works.